# how to z-index parent's background

Tags: css, z-index

So here is what I'm trying to do.

```
<div class="gallery">
<a href="link_to_large_image.jpg" style="z-index:2; position:relative; background: url(roundedcorners.jpg) norepeat;">
<img src="thumbnail.jpg" style="z-index:1; position:relative;" />
</a>
</div>
```

In the gallery I'm trying to place `<a>` (and its background) tag which is the parent of the `<img>` tag on top with the `z-index`. So that way I can add rounded corners to the images.

But looks like no matter what I do it places the background of the `<a>` (which is the rounded corners) under the image.

Any one know the fix?
Here is the link http://ewsbuild.com/~markdemi/gallery.html

Comment: What? I have no idea what you want.

Comment: Please note that you need to wrap your html tags like so: ``<a>`` for them to not get stripped. And please indent your code blocks so they 1) do not get stripped and 2) are formatted correctly.

Comment: Use PNG. Use a div with divs having z-index set.

Comment: You're trying to make the images corners look rounded by making the parent element's background cover them? I'm still a bit confused here.

Comment: yes, rounded corners image is a transparent png with the white corners

Answer (score 1):

If you want rounded corners on images, just do:

```
.lightbox{
    border-radius:15px;
    -moz-border-radius:15px;
}
```

You can change the radius and what elements it affects of course.

Comment: Oh, that's true. What background image are you using? You could use javascript to append a div in front of the image and the same size as it with the background.

Comment: oh i got it to work with not a as clean of a code as i wanted to http://ewsbuild.com/~markdemi/gallery.html but it works

Answer (score 1):

Place a Div inside the a tag and apply the following styling to each div.

```
background: url("images/gallery/Giallo-Sienna-Fireplace.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
height: 153px;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is twofold:

- When you raise the z-index of the `a` you raise the z-index of its children too, so that you're effectively not doing anything by doing this.  Lowering the z-index of the `img` tag should do it.
- z-index only applies to *positioned* elements.  So you need to add `position:relative` to anything you add a z-index to (assuming it doesn't already have a position of course).

Comment: i have added the possition: relateve and made z-index of img to be 1 still it doesnt do anything.